# Are OverflowAI and Stack Overflow Labs the same thing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, stack-overflow-labs, overflowai, generative-ai

https://stackoverflow.co/labs has several sections having buttons and links.

## Box below the page title

[image: Buttons]

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | Get previews and early access to our public platform features Sign Up | For more information about Stack Overflow for Teams Contact Sales |

## Box near the bottom of the page:

[image: GenAI]

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | **GenAI** | We’ve launched the GenAI Stack Exchange site: a site for Q&A on writing or engineering effective prompts while utilizing different generative AI tools. |

Where it will be on-topic to ask "Are OverflowAI and Stack Overflow Labs the same thing?" Should this be on-topic in [GenAI Stack Exchange](https://genai.stackexchange.com)? Should this question be asked on Stack Overflow Meta, Meta Stack Exchange, or should it be asked only to Stack Overflow Sales?

---

The top item in the News and articles section points to [Announcing OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/), an article posted at https://stackoverflow.blog announcing OverflowAI. At the beginning of the blog article, there is a link to OverflowAI pointing to https://stackoverflow.co/labs. Later the article has link a "Stack Overflow Labs"  also pointing to https://stackoverflow.co/labs, besides being repetitive and confusing there is some sort of  recursion.

Comment: That depends on the question, given that both have some direct and indirect implications on the community that would be on topic here, while also having questions that would be entirely irrelevant here.

Comment: @KevinB OverflowAI / Stack Overflow Labs point to each other, some sort of recursive joke, like Google old results page for recursive

Comment: @ChatGPT that's likely by design, given both pages are created by marketing who value engagement metrics.

Comment: @KevinB I edited the question to make it ask for a site recommendation about were to ask if OverflowAI and Stack Overflow Labs are the same thing.

Comment: That doesn't change anything about my statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, OverflowAI is an umbrella term covering several LLM-based tools/projects using Stack Overflow questions and answers as a source and Stack Overflow Labs is a sort of... press location or advertisement landing page for all things related to Stack Overflow products, which includes OverflowAI and the new GenAI stack.

The site seems to focus primarily on paid products and public Q&A features that would support the sale/marketing of paid products. I wouldn't consider it to be a great resource for community related features/announcements given it is unlikely to feature things that aren't relevant to paid products.

---

Questions about actions the company are taking and initiatives the company are running are on topic on MSE, however support questions about paid products generally aren't.